# Is there an API to tap to Apple's Bonjour service?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, bonjour

Is there an API to tap to Apple's Bonjour service (I'm planning to share my non iTunes library with iPad)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Apple doc - [Bonjour API Architecture.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/programming.html)